# how to set radio group WRAP_CONTENT by java coding

Tags: android, android-layout

i have create radio group by using java code in android but i don't know how to set it as WRAP_CONTENT in relative layout.....

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(0);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    layout.addView(radioGroup);
    RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioButtonView.setText("radio1");
    radioButtonView.setId(id++);
    radioButtonView.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.e404);
    radioButtonView.setChecked(false);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);

    RadioButton radioButtonView2 = new RadioButton(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioButtonView2.setText("radio2");
    radioButtonView2.setId(id++);
    radioButtonView2.setChecked(false);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView2, p);
    RadioButton radioButtonView3 = new RadioButton(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioButtonView3.setText("radio3");
    radioButtonView3.setId(id++);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView3, p);
    radioButtonView3.setChecked(false);
    TextView txt = new TextView(Rate_me_up.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using your `LayoutParams` when you add the `RadioGroup` to the `RelativeLayout` instead of when you add your `RadioButton`s to your `RadioGroup`.